# jQuery.data() with CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I change with `setAttribute('color', 'black')` the CSS of some element. After this element will be stored in a jQuery.data() object. But in my data() object the CSS which I defined before won't be stored.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Can you show us your example code ? perhaps on http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: setting an attribute is not the same as setting the CSS. What you want is the `.css()` function, not `.setAttribute()`.

Answer (score 3):

If I have:

```
<div class="element"></div>
```

With jquery you can do:

```
$(".element").css("color", "black");
```

This will render the following:

```
<div class="element" style="color:black;"></div>
```

---

However using setAttribute will render:

```
<div class="element" color="black"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

`setAttribute` does not alter CSS. It alters attributes.

If you want to set CSS then you would:

```
element.style.color = 'black';
```